# Получение координат указателя мыши относительно окна

Tags: java, события, mouse-event, мышь

Так я получаю позицию мыши относительно экрана, а не окна:

```
static int mousex;
static int mousey;

public void mouse(){
    this.mousex=(int)MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getX();
    this.mousey=(int)MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getY();
}
```

Как получить координаты именно относительно окна?

Comment: Возьмите координаты своего окно и эти величины вычте из абсолютных коорданат

Comment: `SwingUtilities.convertPointFromScreen(MouseInfo.getPointerIn‌​fo().getLocation(), component)`

Comment: еще одно решение http://stackoverflow.com/a/29187822/6300555

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать сделать также, как посоветовали мне: [Координаты мыши возле указателя (стрелочки) в Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/628897/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-java).

Создаёте на панели, или на окне, метку и при движении указателя мыши меняете её координаты, одновременно выводя их на ней.