# Координаты мыши возле указателя (стрелочки) в Java

Tags: java, swing, graphics, mouse-event

У меня есть класс на основе `JFrame`, в нём помещён экземпляр другого класса, на основе `JPanel`, в котором создан `g.create(...)` (`Graphics2D`), и мне нужно, чтобы около указателя мыши показывались его координаты.
К сожалению, ни добавление `MouseListener` на сам `JFrame`, ни на `JPanel` не даёт этого результата. Пытался вывести на экран следующим образом:

```
addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override

            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                super.mouseMoved(e);
                g.drawString("x: " + e.getX() + ", y: " + e.getY(), e.getX(), e.getY());
                repaint();
            }
        });
```

И так далее. Ничего не помогает, много способов перепробовал.
Как это можно реализовать?
Если так сделать нельзя, ты было бы хорошо хотя бы поменять текст в `JLabel`, который находится в другом классе (на основе `JPanel`), который помещён в `JFrame`... Много выходит пояснений, но суть в том, что, если бы `JLabel` находился прямо внутри `JFrame`, в коде класса, и координаты я бы отмерял тоже в `JFrame`, это получилось бы легко, а вот когда всё друг в друга обёрнуто и описано в разных классах в разных файлах - не получается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант, можно добавить на панель метку и при движении мыши менять ее координаты. Ниже привожу пару вариантов: с обычной меткой на другой  панели (но она объявлена в самом классе JFrame), и с "безликой" меткой на первой панели. При движении выбираем из списка компонентов на первой панели эту метку, меняем ей текст, размер и размещение. Единственная проблема -- это если на первой панели есть еще метки, то нужна дополнительная проверка, чтобы их не брать.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class FrameProba extends JFrame {    

    private JLabel lbStaticLabel;

    public FrameProba() {
        super("Frame");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(400, 400);

        JPanel pnlPanel1 = new JPanel();
        pnlPanel1.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {      
                lbStaticLabel.setText("X: " + e.getX() + ", Y: " + e.getY());

                JLabel lbMoveLabel = null;
                for(Component c :  pnlPanel1.getComponents()) {
                    if(c.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("JLabel"))
                        lbMoveLabel = (JLabel) c;
                }

                if( lbMoveLabel != null) {
                    lbMoveLabel.setText("" + e.getX() + " " + e.getY());            
                    FontMetrics fm = lbMoveLabel.getGraphics().getFontMetrics();
                    lbMoveLabel.setLocation(e.getX(), e.getY() + 20);   // чуть ниже курсора мышки, чтоб было видно
                    lbMoveLabel.setSize(fm.stringWidth(lbMoveLabel.getText()), fm.getHeight());
                }

            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(pnlPanel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pnlPanel1.setLayout(null);

        pnlPanel1.add(new JLabel());      // добавляем "безликую" метку

        JPanel pnlPanel2 = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(pnlPanel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        lbStaticLabel = new JLabel("");
        pnlPanel2.add(lbStaticLabel);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public tatic void main(Stsring[] args) {
               new FrameProba();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Дико подтормаживает :)
2. Появляется не пойми что с разных сторон от JPanel'и, на которой я замеряю и отображаю координаты: скриншот (https://vk.cc/6galFF)

Comment: Трудно по скрину что-то понять. Где координаты должны отображаться? И где этот элемент (метка, поле??) объявлен -- в общем фрейме или классе, который наследует `JPanel`, а этот класс уже на фрейме? Как в методе mouseMoved присваиваются координаты?